# Get the length based on specific condition using Angular.js

Tags: html, angularjs

We have the below HTML code which uses Angular.js,

```
<div ng-if="$scope.IsResult == false">
  <label style="font-weight: bold;"> Count : {{student.length }}</label>
</div>
```

Here the student is the JSON array returned and contains few records with student.Active=false.

Currently its displaying all students count. 
We need to display the length only for active students i.e student.Active=true. How can I achieve this in Angular.js.

Please advise.

Comment: I created a [library](https://bitbucket.org/no1_melman/simplelinq/overview) which gives you some simple functions to manipulate arrays. You can use `.Count({ active: true})` to find how many items have active set to true!

Comment: @No1_Melman [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) is another great library which has a lot of functions like this, it's like Linq for Javascript, very cool

Comment: @JMK Yeah, the aim with my library is to allow the user to add what ever they wish using the underlying api. But also to be minimalistic in terms footprint and code. There are plenty of other libraries out there for dealing with this problem. I just created my library for this exact situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be best putting a function in your controller which calculates this and calling that from your view.

So in your controller:

```
$scope.countInactiveStudents = function(student){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < student.length; i++){
        if(!student[i].Active){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

And in your view:

```
<label style="font-weight: bold;"> Count : {{countInactiveStudents(student) }}</label>
```

Comment: you should replace "i++" to "count++" :)

Comment: Wow it worked Thanks. Ya it was count++ then it worked.